# 32 bit versions vs 64 versions of Linux

Tags: 64bit, 32bit, distributions

I am currently using various live Linux versions.

In most cases I have the choice between a 64 bit and 32 bit versions.

Does 32 bit have any disadvantages other than slightly lower performance?

What about available software, drivers etc?

Which versions are generally best supported?

One of the machines I might use them on is a 32bit, so those distros are a bit more flexible for me.

Also, if footprint is a bit smaller on a 32bit, there is less data to move from a Live USB etc.

Mainly Mint and Ubuntu for now, but availability of packages are quite important. (Especially system tools)

Comment: It's simple: if you have less than 4 GB of RAM, use 32 bits, else use 64 bits! And of course you can't use 64 bits if the CPU doesn't support it.

Comment: I'd only use 32 bit if the computer can't run 64 bit. Then you don't have to reinstall after upgrading the memory, Also, some programs (especially PHP) have stupid limitations on 32 bit.

Comment: @duplicators: It is different because usually the main consern is performanca, I am more interested in software, support etc.

Comment: @Olav: Believe you have to *carefully* read the linked answer and see if it truly do not meet your needs. If not do an edit with emphasis on what you need that is not answered elsewhere. If a reopen-vote is not cast, you can try [chat], the room is `\dev\chat`, for advice or clarification of whether it can be re-opened – or perhaps you even get a satisfying answer. Note that re-open is a slim hope ... As your question stands now it is also somewhat broad.